# C - Entering values for 2d Array using for loop produces different values than entered

Tags: c, arrays

I have this simple program I am working on in class, it initialized a 3x5 2d Array of integers whose values are inputted for each cell by the user. The program then calls a function which runs through the array with a for loop to display each value, then calls a function which again uses a for loop to double every value, and calls the previous display function to show the array again.

All of this seems to be working, however I am consistently getting odd outputs for certain areas when initializing the values for the 2dArray.

For example: Entering 5 rows of "1, 2, 3" and then calling the display function produces this as output:

```
1,1,2,
1,2,3,
1,2,3,
1,2,5,
1,2,3
```

Further more, the doubling function produces further strange results but only in the areas where the output was different from what the user had inputted. 
Output of the double function on the array I just posted displays as:

```
2,4,8
2,4,6
2,4,6
2,4,10,
4,8,6
```

The only real mathematical operation in the entire program is in the doubling functions, where it runs through a for loop setting the value of "array[j][i] = (array[j][i] = array[j][i] * 2)"

I cannot for the life of me figure out which part of the program I've written would cause the user inputs to change to what has been displayed. Inputting values other than "1,2,3" produces similarly odd results. Anyone have any idea what is wrong here? I feel like it must be a very simple mistake I am missing. Here is my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void displayArray(int array[][4]);
void doubleArray(int array[][4]);


int main() {

    int dArray[2][4];
    int i, j, k;

    for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
        for(j = 0; j <= 2; j++){
            printf("Enter a value for the array at position %d,%d.\n", j, i);
            scanf("%d", &dArray[j][i]); 
        }
    }
    printf("Displaying your original array...\n");
    displayArray(dArray);
    printf("Doubling your array...\n");
    doubleArray(dArray);
    printf("Displaying your doubled array....\n");
    displayArray(dArray);
    system("pause");

}

void displayArray(int array[][4]){
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
        printf("\n");
        for(j = 0; j <= 2; j++){
            if(j == 2 && i == 4){
                printf("%d", array[j][i]);
            }
            else{
                printf("%d,", array[j][i]);
            }
            //system("pause");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void doubleArray(int array [][4]){
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
        for(j = 0; j <= 2; j++){
            array[j][i] = (array[j][i] * 2);
            //printf("%d\n", array[j][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

It's all in one .c file, and I am using devc++ if that makes any difference.

Comment: You go out of bounds of your arrays, leading to *undefined behavior*. If you declare an array with four elements, what are the valid indexes?

Comment: Is that what it is? I was wondering about that.. wouldnt it start with [0][0] being the first position? Should I declare them as like dArray[3][5]? Gonna try it now.

Comment: To answer your question, as I understand is the valid indexes would be [0] - [3]

Comment: I tried making my array declaration "dArray[3][5]" without changing anything else, the program runs exactly the same. Am I misunderstanding your comment? Thank you

Comment: Another issue is the loop condition, for example `for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++)`, the loop increments `i` from 0 to 4, you'll need to change it to `for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)`, so that it exits the loop when `i` reaches 4

Comment: Thanks ccoder, I see what you're saying. However; I wanted there to be 5 rows, so wouldn't having it go to "<=4" be a valid way to do this?

Comment: Yea sorry, this code may be a bit sloppy. The input function works and allows me to entire overall 15 values, and it displays them similarly. I think in that respect I've written it functionally even if it isn't done in the optimal way. I cannot for the life of me figure out why certain values are changing though. 

Especially because it's only at certain positions. I don't see where there is math which would alter the input.

Comment: Yes that is correct actually, I was going by the dArray[2][4] declaration. If you've changed the dArray declaration to dArray[3][5], ensure the input parameters for the `displayArray(..)` and `doubleArray(..)` functions are updated accordingly

Comment: Ah ok, good point. I have the parameters done correctly besides that though, right? The first set of brackets can remain empty, and the second needs to specify number of rows? 


gonna see if changing the parameters fixes anything now.

Comment: Ok CCoder, you were right. Changing the function parameters to [][5] fixed everything. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the DIMENSIONS of your 2D C arrays you have to count how many columns and how many rows there are. In your examples, it is 3 columns and 5 rows, and those are the values you must enter in your array definition:
   int array[3][5]

Then, because C starts indexing with 0 offset, you can referr to the elements of the array using the columns 0 to 2 (that is, 3 columns) and rows 0 to 4 (that is, 5 rows). As other people said, this can be achieved using "lower than the limit" (correct: <3 for the columns, <5 for the rows) instead of "lower or equal than the limit" (incorrect, out of bounds: <=3 for the columns, <=5 for the rows).

Comment: Yep that was it. Go figure it was a simple mistake. I appreciate the answer!